# What does instruct means for a deep learning model?

Tags: deep-learning, model

On HuggingFace there are deeplearning models that you can download, some with the "instruct" part in their name, for example [LLaMa-7B-Instruct](https://huggingface.co/TheBloke/CodeLlama-7B-Instruct-GGUF).

I don't understand what this means VS a regular model. Has the model already been trained in a specific way ? Or is it ready to be trained ? Or is it ready to run already ?

Thank you

I googled it and did not find a clear definition that helps me to understand globally. I asked chatGPT and Perplexity but didn't find a clear answer neither.